# How to fill each particular span with hyperlinks' title attribute's value?

Tags: jquery

I wonder how it could be done with *jQuery*:

This is how I render each hyperlink which has "title" attribute:

```
<a class="tooltip" title="some description">some text
<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</a>
```

I would like each hyperlink to have "Tooltip text" replaced by their own "title" attibute's value (e.g. here "Tooltip text" should be changed into "some description"). Could someone help with this challenge?

Comment: Have you written any code, made any attempts, or done any research? Without including these, your question reads as if you're just asking someone to write code for you. These questions are generally not received well because they are **off-topic**.

Comment: Ok, next time I will include the description of what I've attempted to do, I didn't know it is a good practice, especially given that I saw many similar requests here. Thank You for pointing this out, writing is difficult for Me because of weak vision, and "the funny thing" about it is that I treat writing and publishing posts on My issues as the last thing, when everything else failed. I would rather find the answer by Myself, but not always I am successful in this regard, especially given that I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through each `tooltip` link and set the HTML of the title property.

```js
$(".tooltip").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".tooltiptext").html($(this).prop("title"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tooltip" title="some description">some text
<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</a>
```